# How to AVCaptureSession.sessionPreset to 720x1280px(or 1/1.77 scale of anything)

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I am using swift3 and can't change my resolution to custom values when i use AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium etc. it doesn't fit the screen scale(1/1.77).

```
    let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

    output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: sampleQueue)

    let metaOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    metaOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: faceQueue)

    session.beginConfiguration()
```

//        Desired resolution : 720x1280px
//        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

```
    if session.canAddInput(input) {
        session.addInput(input)
    }
    if session.canAddOutput(output) {
        output .alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true;
        session.addOutput(output)
        connection1 = output.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        connection1?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto;
        connection1?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        connection1?.isVideoMirrored = true;
    }
    if session.canAddOutput(metaOutput) {
        output .alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true;
        session.addOutput(metaOutput)
        connection2 = metaOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeMetadata)
        connection2?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto;
        connection2?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        connection2?.isVideoMirrored = true
    }
```

Comment: You can set AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 instead of AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium

Comment: My screen is portrait so the height should be higher than the width. I must set the upper limit to 720x1280px or lower in same (1/1.77) rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720` preset. The presets are denoted in landscape but the capture setting of 1280x720 is the same as 720x1280 the only difference is the orientation. For example with an app that supports rotation:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
{
    guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
    cameraImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
    print(cameraImage?.extent ?? "")
}
```

Will print `(0.0, 0.0, 1280.0, 720.0)` when in landscape, and `(0.0, 0.0, 720.0, 1280.0)` when in portrait.

Comment: Thank you, but the whole app is used in portrait orientation and I think rotating for a single VC is not so good for usage. I think decreasing the resolution after getting the sample buffer can be useful too, do you know how to do it(using vImage or etc.)?

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The configuration is the same whether you want the video stream in portrait or landscape i.e. `AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720` == `AVCaptureSessionPreset720x1280`

Comment: Ah you are right. It automatically makes is 720x1280px. What a shame that I didn't see this. Thank you so much.